# GPS from street+city+country

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I need to put some markers on my map in my site and my android app .
Is there any chance to get GPS if I have data : name of street, city and country ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google term you're looking for is Geocoding. Yahoo and Google have services for it, among others.

eg http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html